Python Flask UnderIIS - Docx to Pdf
I have an flask app under my windows server and i would like it to convert docx to pdf without changing the docx file. I have tried to do it with comptypes code below, but it doesn't work because windows doesnt allow it.
What are the other options?
Here is the error that i am getting
(-2147024891, 'Access is denied', None, None)
I am looking to find another package that will convert through requests that has been made to IIS but all of them requires a license.
Final Edit: To everyone who tries to do this by dispatching word.application, you have to change windows component services settings. You have to find Microsoft Word over there and apply security changes for IIS and DefaultApplication User. But i decided to change all my plan to libreoffice which doesnt require such thing but it also has disadvantages such as it will not convert to document 1:1 it will change some stuff.
I am closing the topic now.
def doc2pdf(doc_name, pdf_name, font_size=8):

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
    if os.path.exists(pdf_name):
        os.remove(pdf_name)
    worddoc = word.Documents.Open(doc_name, ReadOnly=1)
    worddoc.Content.Font.Size = font_size
    try:
        worddoc.SaveAs(pdf_name, FileFormat=17)
    except Exception as e:
        createText('wordToPdfException', f"{e}")
    worddoc.Close()
    # Quit the Word application
    word.Quit()
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
    return pdf_name


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Microsoft doesn't support server side Office automation, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2, which applies to all related scenarios including yours. But feasible options are also mentioned in that article.

Your problem is that this code doesn't work on IIS but works locally right? If so, do you get any error messages?

@samwu yeah it works on local but doesnt work on IIS

Doc2Pdf through IIS doesnt work because microsoft doesnt allow it, you have to go to component services of the windows and find Microsoft Word over there and change its security by adding IIS and DefaultAppPool, however, i decided to go with libreoffice which doesnt require these steps, but it has its own disadvantages for example it doesnt convert the document 1:1 it changes some stuff.
